# Abort Twitter XML loading in PHP

Tags: php, xml, twitter

I am loading the Twitter Member XML with the simplexml_load_file() Function.

This works fine and i can parse the XML, but sometime it needs alot Time to
load the XML or the XML does not load becouse of Twitter. And this is not only
becouse of the 150 Request Limits from Twitter.

Thats why i would like to know if it is possible to abort the Twitter XML File
loading after 30 Seconds when the loading was not successful until then?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is much you can do, using `simplexml_load_file()`.

However, when retrieving the content of the URL using cURL, you can specify a timeout:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // <- Timeout in Seconds
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

$xml = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would think of is using AJAX. Create a call to the PHP script that performs the load function and let JavaScript abort the AJAX call if it takes more than 30 seconds.

```
$.ajax({'complete': callbackFunction, 'url': 'foo/bar/', 'timeout': 5000, 'error': errorCallback});
```

You are looking for the `timeout` and `error`. The timeout (in ms) aborts the script and calls the `error` function you can use to return a message the action was aborted (or whatever you want to do with it).

You can find more in the
[Jquery Document about AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)